Hiding a row in Report Builder
I am trying to understand the result of summing a Field that has all null / empty values in an expression.
When I display the SUM of fields that are all empty I get no result i.e. an empty text box.  But when I use the below expression to show or hide the text box then the text box gets hidden when all the values are null / empty implying it is summing to Zero.
Sum(Fields!Amount.Value, "Dataset") = 0
I do not want to handle the null / empty values but I want to understand the behaviour of SUM when used in an expression to control visibility.

Null values are ignored by the SUM function is SSRS.

Returns the sum of all the non-null numeric values specified by the
expression, evaluated in the given scope in a paginated report.

Learn.Microsoft
